# Xpages error when saving document in different DB in XPiNC

Tags: xpages

I am running an Xpages db in XPiNC that I want to use as a "front end" to several other databases in our system. I will store the code in this DB and access the data in other DBs.

When I am trying to do a simple CRUD operation on a form I am getting an error that I cannot explain.

```
6/22/15 4:51 PM: Exception Thrown
Context Path: /xsp/<SERVER>NetworkHome.nsf
Page Name: /xpFormHelpDesk.xsp
javax.faces.FacesException
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.access$0(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService$NsfServiceRequest.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService$NsfServiceRequest.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService$NsfServiceThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.dojo.DateTimeHelperRenderer._getConvertedValue(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.dojo.DateTimeHelperRenderer.getConvertedValue(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.getConvertedValue(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getConvertedValue(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIInputEx.getConvertedValue(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.processValidators(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.processValidators(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.processValidators(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.processValidators(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.layout.UIVarPublisherBase.processValidators(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.processValidators(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx._processValidators(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.processValidators(Unknown Source)
    ... 25 more
```

My code in the custom control is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view
    xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex"
    xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">
    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoView
            var="view1"
            databaseName="helpdesk.nsf"
            viewName="My Tickets">
            <xp:this.categoryFilter><![CDATA[#{javascript:@Name("[CN]",session.getEffectiveUserName()) + "Open"}]]></xp:this.categoryFilter>
        </xp:dominoView>
    </xp:this.data>
    <xe:widgetContainer
        id="widgetContainer1"
        style="width:800.px;font-weight:bold;font-size:10pt;margin-left:10.0px"
        dropDownRendered="false"
        titleBarText="My Help Desk Tickets"
        titleBar="true"
        type="sidebar"
        collapsible="false">
        <xp:panel>
            <xp:repeat
                id="repeat1"
                var="rowData"
                indexVar="repeatIndex"
                value="#{view1}">
                <xp:this.facets>
                    <xp:text
                        disableTheme="true"
                        xp:key="header"
                        escape="false">
                        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[<table class='lotusTable repeatRowColors' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
<tr class ='lotusFirst lotusSort scope='col'>
<th class ='lotusBold'>Requester</th>
<th class ='lotusBold'>Subject</th>
<th class ='lotusBold'>Date</th>
</tr>
</thead>]]></xp:this.value>
                    </xp:text>
                    <xp:text
                        disableTheme="true"
                        xp:key="footer"
                        escape="false">
                        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[</table>]]></xp:this.value>
                    </xp:text>
                </xp:this.facets>
                <xp:tr
                    id="rowDataContainer">
                    <xp:td
                        style="width:125.00px;min-width:125px;max-width:125px;font-size:10pt">
                        <xp:text
                            escape="true"
                            id="computedField3">
                            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:rowData.getColumnValue("$0");}]]>
                            </xp:this.value>
                        </xp:text>
                    </xp:td>
                    <xp:td
                        style="width:250px;min-width:250px;max-width:250px font-size:10pt">
                        <xp:link
                            escape="true"
                            id="link1">
                            <xp:this.text><![CDATA[#{javascript:rowData.getColumnValue("Subject2")}]]></xp:this.text>
                            <xp:eventHandler
                                event="onclick"
                                submit="true"
                                refreshMode="complete">
                                <xp:this.action>
                                    <xp:openPage
                                        name="/xpFormHelpDesk.xsp"
                                        target="openDocument">
                                        <xp:this.documentId><![CDATA[#{javascript:rowData.getDocument().getUniversalID()}]]></xp:this.documentId>
                                    </xp:openPage>
                                </xp:this.action>
                            </xp:eventHandler>
                        </xp:link>
                    </xp:td>
                    <xp:td
                        style="font-size:10pt">
                        <xp:text
                            escape="true"
                            id="computedField2">
                            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:rowData.getColumnValue("$1");}]]>
                            </xp:this.value>
                            <xp:this.converter>
                                <xp:convertDateTime
                                    type="date"></xp:convertDateTime>
                            </xp:this.converter>
                        </xp:text>
                    </xp:td>
                </xp:tr>
            </xp:repeat>
        </xp:panel>
    </xe:widgetContainer>
</xp:view>
```

The database that I am getting the data from is not in Xpages, but I don't think that that should matter.

Comment: Is the data database local? Otherwise it will need format ServerName!!DatabasePath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the stack trace, it's failing in Process Validations phase - so checking datatypes for validation / data conversion, and failing on the DateTimeHelperRenderer. It looks like that's pointing to computedField2.

There are two possible explanations:

1. One of the view entries has a value in column $1 that cannot be converted to a date. This sounds the most probable.
2. You're hitting the problem I blogged about with partial refreshes and row datasources not available http://www.intec.co.uk/dataviews-and-nested-repeats/. If this is the case, wrapping the calculation with `if (view.isRenderingPhase()) {...}` will solve the problem. If it's not the case, it will move the error to the Render Response phase.

Comment: Paul, you helped me figure it out. Actually I put the wrong source in the question. In a text field in the form I was saving I had left a <date converter> in there. It was probably from copying and pasting some code and not being too careful. As soon as I removed that, it worked just fine. Thanks!

Comment: Once you can identify the pertinent parts of the stack trace, it's often a lot easier to work out what's going wrong. The bit that's not included is the relevant component's ID, which is what XPages OpenLog Logger (or the version of the code in OpenNTF Domino API) adds.

Answer (score 2):

Your datasource defines `databaseName="helpdesk.nsf"` - in XPiNC it means local replica of the database. You need to use full format, as Paul suggested:

```
databaseName="yourservername!!helpdesk.nsf"
```

I recommend to parametrize the server with:

```
databaseName="#{database.server}!!helpdesk.nsf"
```

I think validator fails because of "no data" from invalid data source.